# grub2: error: can't allocate initrd - chainload an NTFS partition from FAT32 without errors on initial ramdisk (initrd) file

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partition, grub2, uefi

The OS with `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Desktop 64-bit` is located in the gpt2 partition with the filesystem NTFS.

This is the structure of the gpt1 partition with the filesystem FAT32:

```
.
├── boot
│   └── grub
│       └── grub.cfg
└── efi
    └── boot
        ├── bootx64.efi
        ├── grubx64.efi
        └── mmx64.efi

4 directories, 4 files
```

This is the grub menù of the NTFS partition (default grub.cfg):

```
if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

set timeout=5
menuentry "Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity quiet splash ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
menuentry "Ubuntu (safe graphics)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity quiet splash nomodeset ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
grub_platform
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
menuentry 'Boot from next volume' {
    exit 1
}
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' {
    fwsetup
}
fi
```

If the grub.cfg file (FAT32 partition) contains:

```
search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid 2E92F36515DD4A5A
chainloader /EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI
boot
```

After making a choice from the grub selection menu, placed in the default grub.cfg file (NTFS partition) which is the same as the default contained within an iso image of `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Desktop 64-bit`, the error message appears:

```
error: can't allocate initrd.
Press any key to continue...
```

I have to underline that the NTFS partition bootloader starts correctly with the `chainloader` command, otherwise I would not have seen the grub selection menu, it is the `initrd` command that gives an error.

If instead the grub.cfg file (FAT32 partition) contains:

```
search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid 2E92F36515DD4A5A
configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

After the selection menu, everything works correctly, therefore the initrd command no longer gives an error.

What's wrong with running the NTFS partition bootloader to boot `initrd` using the default grub.cfg file inside it?
I have tested that if partition 2 has Windows, using `chainloader` everything works correctly.

UPDATE 1:
I tried to swap partitions, the error persists.

UPDATE 2:
I would like to get more detailed error output from the `initrd` command but I don't know [how to do it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697611/initrd-casper-initrd-verbose-output).
I have tried

```
linux   /casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed nosplash debug ignore_loglevel ---
initrd  /casper/initrd
```

but the error output is still the same, no rows added.

UPDATE 3:
Summarizing and clarifying what I am going to do, I from the partition with FAT32 do the chainload of the bootloader located on the NTFS partition.
If I boot the NTFS partition directly from BIOS, everything works, if instead I chainload starting from the FAT32 partition, problems appear.
Everything works correctly even if I call the menu of the grub.cfg (NTFS partition) using the `configfile` command rather than the `chainloader` command inside the `grub.cfg` file of the FAT32 partition, of which I have already shown the lines it contains.

UPDATE 4:
I am going to use the `chainloader` command anyway for generalization reasons, even being able to use the `configfile` command that would solve the problem, because I would have the possibility to execute the same command both to start a partition with Windows and Ubuntu.

UPDATE 5:
The `ntfs` module is already built into the bootloader of both partitions. The `lsmod` command confirmed this. In any case I have tried to insert `insmod ntfs` in the `grub.cfg` files of both partitions and, as expected, the error does not change.

UPDATE 6:
I don't boot NTFS partition directly from BIOS, because UEFI on older computers cannot read NTFS directly.

UPDATE 7:
I HAVE DISCOVERED AN ERROR! Before I didn't notice it because it lasts a fraction of a second. But with a video from the phone, which I had to set to 60 fps to be able to catch the error, I recorded it, then took it to the PC, from the PC I took a screenshot of that video fragment, then rotated it and cropped with gimp.
The error is as follows:

```
error: can't find command `grub_platform`.
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I do not think any UEFI reads NTFS. UEFI reads FAT32. Why not extract Ubuntu ISO directly into a FAT32 partition, set that partition as ESP with esp, boot flags & boot it?  It did this to extract to second partition on external flash drive. fred@z170-focal-k:~$ `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/fred/temp` & 
`sudo 7z x ~/ISO/jammy-desktop-amd64.iso -o/media/fred/temp`

Comment: Because then this FAT32 + NTFS configuration I will need to do it on a custom Ubuntu distro larger than 4GB. I only use Ubuntu 20.04 because if it works with Ubuntu 20.04, it will also work on the custom distro.

Comment: That distro is larger than 4GB is ok, its just no file can be over 4GB. Do not know why then Microsoft's standard ISO has a .wim file that is over 4GB making it difficult to create a Windows installer. Windows installer splits the .wim when writing it, so why do they not have it that way in ISO?